# Failed to initialize AVAudioRecorder: (null)

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm working on iOS with cordova framework and I've implemented AudioRecorder functionality as described in cordova articles.
When I try to Record an Audio file a message saying "Failed to initialize AVAudioRecorder: (null)" appears.
How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The PhoneGap Media api allows record in `.wav` format (and other types), but not in `mp3`.
Choosing the `mp3` format is a common mistake.

You should save the file as `.wav`.